# Two books by the same author: travel through different times, and news reports of aliens

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, time-travel

I'm looking for two books that I think are by the same author.

I read them both 10/15 years ago, and they're adult scifi/horror type books.

One was about a group of people - I think a mixture of tourists and a couple of archaeologists visiting some sort of ruins (possibly Roman). Somehow they find themselves in a different time ... After a while there, they keep jumping to different times. The main thing I remember is that because things in the ruins changed over time, a person jumping into the past could end up in the same space and time as an object, like a rock. One person jumped into the same place as a bee and had a bee in their face. As they went further back in time, more people become affected, and these people lived in a community together.

The second book has a man as the main character. There are news reports of aliens, and weird things start happening. I don't remember the bulk of the story, but I do remember the end:

> It turned out that there were no aliens, but it was some kind of mass hallucination caused by the earth's magnetic field getting stronger.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time: edit out one of the identification requests, and ask a second question. By the way, the proper tag to use is [tag:story-identification].

Comment: @Gilles I asked both together because they're by the same author, I think, and I thought it might help people remember better.

Comment: That's a good point. Since finding the title once you know the author is usually easy, it doesn't matter if someone only knows the answer to one of the questions (which is the usual problem with double questions). I withdraw my objection.

Comment: The second book, up until the end, sounds like, "Martians Go Home," by Frederic Brown.  All these obnoxious Martians show up, causing mayhem and trouble.  They can appear and disappear at will and start revealing secrets and tattling on people and doing everything they can to create havoc.  It's definitely a comedy.  Toward the end a number of people are working on ideas to get rid of them, so we're never sure just why they were there or just what got rid of them.  There is reason, though, to believe it might be a mass hallucination.

Comment: @TangoOversway I remember them both being serious, maybe even in the sci-fi horror category. And thanks @Gilles.

Answer (score 8):

The second book is almost definitely [*King Blood*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?8629) by [Simon Clark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_Clark).

> After a huge global cataclysm, the protagonist finds himself fleeing 'The Greys' an alien race that seems to be attacking the earth. He eventually figures out that earthquakes / volcanoes caused changes in the magnetic fields that caused mass hallucination, after he almost beats his girlfriend to death in the middle of the night thinking she's a 'Grey'

Comment: It's definitely him. The first book is most likely The Fall: http://www.zone-sf.com/wordworks/fallsclark.html

Comment: To update the comment made by @BBog back in 2012.....I have an ebook of The Fall and there is definitely a section where a character has a bee in their face